# Attempt to access not existing network path

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix3.8

During installation of my application, one of the input parameters is a path to folder where audio files would be stored. This path supports UNC path and can be changed during software lifetime. If I run installer when software installed in order to perform change / repair or uninstall and originally provided path is not available I receive following error:

[image]

The error occur in very beginning, seems after "Computing space requirements" stage. How can this check be avoided?

Comment: You may have a custom action that wants to access that original path, or if you installed files to that network location then certainly the uninstall of part of the product will want to remove files from that original location if they were installed there. Might that explain it?

Comment: No, i don't have such custom actions. Also it is installed on local drive. That issue happens as installer is fired.

Comment: ok, set the logging policy as here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 set the options to voicewarmup and the uninstall of the component (do you mean feature?) will generate a log called MSInnn.log in the temp folder, where nnn is a hex string. Post that log somewhere so we can see what's going on when it goes to that URL.